# Find the solution to the given derivative of the product: $\big(\cos{x}\delta{x}\big)^{(k)}$

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

> Find the solution to the given derivative of the product
> $$\big(\cos{x}\delta{x}\big)^{(k)}$$

We need to use the differentiation formula for generalized functions:

$$\big(D^\alpha f, \phi)=(-1)^{|\alpha|}(f,D^\alpha\phi)$$
with $a(x)=cos{x}$, $f=\delta(x)$,  and $\alpha=k $

$$\big(D^k(\cos{x},\delta(x))=-1^{k}\int\cos{x} D^{(k)}\delta(x)\text{d}x=D^{(k)}\delta(x)$$

Although the answer is right, I can't  make sense of that $\cos{x}$ gives $1$ in order to obtain the right answer.

Any ideas on how to get that last integral right?

Thanks

Comment: The notation is confusing. Does “$\cos x \delta x$” mean $\cos x$ times the Dirac delta $\delta(x)$? (In that case, can't you just use $f(x) \, \delta(x) = f(0) \, \delta(x)$ *before* differentiating?)

Comment: @HansLundmark yes, that is the product of the two.

Comment: Which idiot gave this a thumb down? The answer is far from easy, and it has been supplied below.

Comment: I was the downvoter. I think your question is lacking context. You should edit your post to include the definition of $\cos(x)\cdot \delta(x)$; what does it _mean_ to multiply a distribution by a smooth function? Only when you understand that can you begin the problem of finding the $k^\text{th}$ derivative of such a product.

Comment: @MikeEarnest you have quite a high expectation off question quality. I didn't know about that identity, and it was hear that I learned it, thanks to the answers. Knowing of more identities does not qualify to prevent from down-voting.  It is rather the opposite, adding such identities gives upvoting.

Answer (score 2):

**Lemma:** $\newcommand{\ph}{\varphi}\cos(x)\cdot \delta(x)=\delta(x)$.

*Proof:* In order to prove prove that two distributions $T_1$ and $T_2$ are equal, it is necessary and sufficient to show that $(T_1,\ph)=(T_2,\ph)$ for all test functions $\ph\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$. Letting $\ph\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ be an arbitrary test function, we compute
$$
\begin{align}
(\cos x\cdot\,\delta(x), \ph(x)) 
&= (\delta(x), \cos(x) \cdot  \ph(x)) 
\\&= \cos(0)\cdot  \ph(0) 
\\&= \ph(0) 
\\&= (\delta(x), \ph(x)).
\end{align}
$$
The first equality is the only one that needs a little justification. It follows from the [definition of the product of a distribution with a smooth function (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Multiplication_of_distributions_by_smooth_functions). From the link, we see that if $T$ is a distribution, and $m$ is any smooth function, then the product $m\cdot T$ is defined by $(m(x)\cdot T,\ph(x))=(T,m(x)\cdot \ph(x))$. Conclude by letting $T=\delta$ and $m=\cos$.

This completes the proof that $\cos(x)\cdot \delta(x)=\delta(x)$.$\tag*{$\square$}$

Since $\cos(x)\cdot \,\delta(x) = \delta(x)$, it immediately follows that $(\cos(x)\cdot \, \delta(x))^{(k)} =  \delta(x)^{(k)}$. To be complete, we should describe how $\delta^{(k)}(x)$ acts on test functions, but this is easy:
$$
(\delta^{(k)}(x),\ph(x))=(-1)^k (\delta(x),\ph^{(k)}(x))=(-1)^k \ph^{(k)}(0).
$$

Comment: George, thanks for the answer. But why did you zero- the delta function, when it was $\delta(x)$ in the original function to be differentiated, and in fact, the right answer is $D^\alpha\delta(x)$

Comment: It means the Dirac delta at the point zero (i.e., the notations $\delta_0$ and $\delta(x)$ mean the same thing).

Comment: @Luthier415Hz I'm assuming you want the dirac delta centred at zero, if you centre it at $x$ instead you have $\cos x \partial^\alpha \delta_x$ as the derivative.

Comment: @GeorgeC yes,  your last answer is the right one. The assumption of having dirac delta at zero is not said in the exercise. However, what is that $\bullet$ symbol?

Comment: @Luthier415Hz I write it like that to avoid it being read as $\cos(\delta_0)$ or something. It just means cosine times dirac delta

Comment: I see, I have never seen cosine of "nothing", only $\cos{x}$, but no matter. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Luthier415Hz: The notation $\delta(x)$ invariably means the Dirac distribution (although written so that it looks like it's a function) at the *origin*. With this notation, if it's centered at the point $a$ it's written as $\delta(x-a)$. It makes little sense to say that it's centered at the point $x$ in this context, since $x$ is used as a free variable in $\cos x$.

Answer (score -2):

Find the solution to the given derivative of the product  $$\big(\cos{x}\delta(x)\big)^{(k)}$$

$$\big(D^\alpha f,\phi\big)=(-1)^{|\alpha|}(f,D^{\alpha}\phi),$$ with $f(x)=\cos{x}$, $a(x)=\delta(x)$ and $\phi(x)$,  and $\alpha=k $

$m=1$

Then, by the rule $\big(f(x)a(x),\phi(x)\big)=\big((f(x),a(x)\phi(x)\big)$

$$\big(\cos{x}\delta(x)\big)^{\prime}=\big(\cos{x}'\delta(x),\phi(x)+\cos{x}\delta'(x),\phi(x)\big)$$

$$\big(\cos{x}\delta(x)\big)^{\prime}=\big((\delta'(x),\cos{x}\phi(x))+(\delta(x),\cos{x}'\phi(x)\big)$$

Let us split, consider the first part on the LHS above:

$$\big(\delta'(x),\cos{x}\phi(x)\big)\implies$$
$$- (\delta (x), [\cos x \phi(x)]')=
- \big(\delta (x),  \cos x \phi'(x))
+ (\delta (x),  \sin x \phi'(x)\big)= $$
$$-(\delta (x),  \cos x \phi'(x))= - \phi'(0)= \big(\delta'(x), \phi(x)\big)=\delta'(x)$$

and consider the second part on the LHS above
$$\big(\delta(x),\cos{x}'\phi(x)\big)=\big(\delta'(x),\cos{x}\phi(x)\big)=\delta'(x)$$

We sum up, and obtain:

$$\big(\cos{x}\delta(x)\big)^{\prime}=2\delta'(x)$$

Comment: This answer disagrees with the earlier answer. I challenge you to find the [error in the proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4862140/177399) (now updated). You will fail, since there is no error.

Comment: The error in _your_ proof is when you say $(D^k(\cos x, \delta(x))=(-1)^k \int \cos x D^{(k)}\delta(x)\,dx$. This does NOT follow from your previous equation, $\big(D^\alpha f,\phi\big)=(-1)^{|\alpha|}(f,D^{\alpha}\phi),$ with the substitutions you said. The correct way to make your substitutions is
$$
\big(D^k \cos x,\delta(x)\big)=(-1)^{k}(\cos x ,D^{k}\delta(x))
$$
However, that is completely unrelated to your problem, because $$(D^k \cos x, \delta(x))\neq D^k(\cos x, \delta(x))$$You can see how you the order of parentheses and $D$ confused.

Comment: You are right. I have corrected the first part now. It was not shown which rule I used. Actually $(D^k\cos x, \delta(x))=(\cos x, D^k\delta(x)))$